# VB.net 2010 XML Nodes parsing

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, vb.net-2010

Im trying to get some help with XML. I have found some good code examples online and it works for most of what i'm trying to get, but not for all.  Any Help with this would be nice. I only get the combined data. I'm looking on how to get "ns0:NarrativeCreateDatetime" on the loop in one object and the "ns0:NarrativeText" in the an other object.

Thanks
Fernando

Part Of the xml File:

09/14/2012 07:49:23 - E911 Info - Class of Service: BUSN

```
for Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In Narrative
        If Not item.InnerText = "" Then

            objNarrative = item.InnerText
            x += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In DispatchTime
        If Not item.InnerText = "" Then
            For Each UnitNumber As System.Xml.XmlElement In item.GetElementsByTagName("ns0:UnitNumber")
                objUnitNumber = UnitNumber.InnerText
            Next
            For Each Dispatched As System.Xml.XmlElement In item.GetElementsByTagName("ns0:Dispatched")
                objUnitDispatched = Dispatched.InnerText
            Next
            For Each Enroute As System.Xml.XmlElement In item.GetElementsByTagName("ns0:Enroute")
                objUnitEnRoute = Enroute.InnerText
            Next
            For Each AtScene As System.Xml.XmlElement In item.GetElementsByTagName("ns0:AtScene")
                objUnitAtScene = AtScene.InnerText
            Next
            For Each InService As System.Xml.XmlElement In item.GetElementsByTagName("ns0:InService")
                objUnitInService = InService.InnerText
            Next
            ' Add Code to insert to DB



            objUnitNumber = ""
            objUnitDispatched = ""
            objUnitEnRoute = ""
            objUnitAtScene = ""
            objUnitInService = ""
        End If
    Next
```